# Fixing the grails validation error for a blank , null field in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

There is a domain class **Person** in which a field has constraint like

```
AnnualIncome(blank:true, nullable:true,range: 100000..100000000).
```

If the user does not want to fill this field then the default value of this filed is 0 and then  there is a grails default exception raised which says that the value of `AnnualIncome` does not fall in the of 100000 to 100000000 .

But this constraints comes in use when user fills `AnnualIncome` field and then  the range constraint is applied .But how to manage this state that the constraint is checked when user wishes to fill this detail and if he doesn't want to fill it , no exception should be raised ??

Comment: You should follow the naming convention that is field name "AnnualIncome" should be in camel case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) on range field for your use case:

in validator closure you can apply your constraint conditionally.

in validator closure you can check

```
if(AnnualIncome ==0){
    //do somthing
 }else{
   // apply constraint here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you allow `null` set the value to `null` instead of `0`.  This makes it even easier to distinquish between a value **not** set or an actual `0` entered (which might change at some point in the future e.g. because you allow NPOs to register).

Otherwise you should remove the range check.  If it is not relevant for **storing** the data, then it should be dealt with on the domain model level (GORM objects are not domain model).

Comment: That can be an easy alternative but By default grails is setting this value as zero. But how to set it as null ??

Comment: @user3789902 what type is `AnnualIncome`?

Comment: @user3789902 beside that `float` is totally unreliable for monetary values, it is a java base type and can not be set to `null`.  Use `Float` (capital F) if you must or better a `BigDecimal` or something, that fits your actual database.